# Не работает git через cmd

Tags: windows, git, cmd, git-cmd

Установил git отсюда https://git-scm.com/downloads
в Path прописался путь. Но cmd все еще его почему то не видит. Переписал пути на `C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_cf76fc1621ac41ad4fe86c420ab5ff403f1808b9`
Итог один, cmd все еще не видит его. Что можно сделать?

Comment: Пробовали открыть новое окно cmd?

Comment: потому что после установки в программах появляется `git gui`(графический интерфейс) и `git bash` (собственно сама строка) в котором все эти команды и вводятся.... смотрите в `c:\Program Files\Git`

Comment: @Geslot спасибо добрый человек,  помогло)

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего когда ты скачивал GIT то ты не указал значение
"добавить в PATH" переустанови git и поставь это значение

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1264958/edit)

Comment: Причина же указана в комментариях, вы их не читали? Для того, чтобы добавить что-то в PATH, не надо ничего переустанавливать.